# Stackdriver advanced filter query without wildcards

Tags: logging, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have logs being sent in JSON format to Stackdriver, each which contains an entry like:

`name: pipeline.<application>.process`

where `<application>` is a variable length string that represents various components in our system.

I would like a query to get all such logs, however, don't know how to do so given that stackdriver doesn't support wildcards or regex.

Ideally, something like a `pipeline.*.process` would be great, but I can't figure it out from the docs. Equally, `<application>` takes >40 forms, and so I don't want to create a custom metric for every one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filtering for

```
jsonPayload.name: "pipeline."
jsonPayload.name: ".process"
```

should give you the results you want

If you're interested in building a metric you can create a single log based metric that extracts the  portion of the name value: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels